# Reverse geocoding in an array formula in google sheets for state and county

Tags: google-sheets, reverse, geocoding

I have the below code for reverse geocoding in google sheets to find the US state and county. It works but I need to use it in an array formula and can't figure it out. I am fairly new to coding so please be kind.

```
    `/**
     * Return the closest, human-readable address type based on the the latitude and longitude values     specified.
     *
     * @param   {"locality"}  addressType Address type. Examples of address types include
     *                                    a street address, a country, or a political entity.
     *                                    For more info check:       https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#Types
    * @param   {"52.379219"} lat         Latitude
    * @param   {"4.900174"}  lng         Longitude
    * @customfunction
    */
    function reverseGeocode(addressType, lat, lng) {
    Utilities.sleep(1500);

    if (typeof addressType != 'string') {
        throw new Error("addressType should be a string.");
    }

    if (typeof lat != 'number') {
        throw new Error("lat should be a number");
    }

    if (typeof lng != 'number') {
        throw new Error("lng should be a number");
    }

    var response = Maps.newGeocoder().reverseGeocode(lat, lng),
        key      = 'KEY';
    response.results.some(function (result) {
        result.address_components.some(function (address_component) {
            return address_component.types.some(function (type) {
                if (type == addressType) {
                    key = address_component.long_name;
                    return true;
                }
            });
        });
    });
    return key;
    }`
```

with this formula in the cell:
=iferror(reverseGeocode("administrative_area_level_2", A1, B1),"Not Supplied")

if I try to put it in an arrayformula like this: =arrayformula(iferror(reverseGeocode("administrative_area_level_2", A1:A, B1:B),"Not Supplied"))

it does not work, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

#### Modification points:

- When `=arrayformula(iferror(reverseGeocode("administrative_area_level_2", A1:A, B1:B),"Not Supplied"))` is run, the 3 arguments are a string, a 2-dimensional array like `[["A1"],["A2"],,,]`, and a 2-dimensional array like `[["B1"],["B2"],,,]`, respectively. But, when I saw your custom function `reverseGeocode`, it seems that the 3 arguments `addressType, lat, lng` are string value. (`lat` and `lng` are number type?). In this case, the values of `[["A1"],["A2"],,,]` and `[["B1"],["B2"],,,]` are used to the 2nd and 3rd arguments, respectively. I thought that the reason for your current issue is due to this.

In order to remove this issue, how about giving the valid arguments to your custom function as follows?

#### Modified formula:

```
=MAP(A1:A,B1:B,LAMBDA(ARGUMENT2,ARGUMENT3,IF(AND(ARGUMENT2<>"",ARGUMENT3<>""),iferror(reverseGeocode("administrative_area_level_2",ARGUMENT2,ARGUMENT3),"Not Supplied"),"")))
```

- By this, without modifying your custom function, the values of "A1:A" and "B1:B" can be used as the 2nd and 3rd arguments.

#### Reference:

- [MAP function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12568985)

Comment: @Sam Nichols Did my answer show you the result that you want? Would you please tell me about it? That is also useful for me to study. If this works, other people who have the same issue as you can also base your question as a question that can be solved. If you have issues with my answer yet, I apologize. At that time, can I ask you about your current situation? I would like to study to solve your issues.